# PHP-return maximum value of any table and column

Tags: php, mysql

I want to create a function in PHP that return a maximum value ,with the particularity that the function receives as parameters the table name and column name where I want to apply the filter maximum value.
For example:

```
function mymaxvalue($nametable,$namecolum)
{

    global $con;
    global $valueMax;
    $sql = "SELECT MAX($namecolum) FROM '$nametable'";

    $result = mysql_query($sql, $con);
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

        echo $temperaturaMax = $row['MAX($namecolum)'] ;


    }

}
```

Unfortunately, when I call the function, it does not work. Thanks for you help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> First of all, don't use `mysql_*` functions as they deprecated and
>   completely removed in PHP 7.

**Two things:**

1) Remove single quote from table name.

Corrected SQL:

```
$sql = "SELECT MAX($namecolum) FROM $nametable";
```

2) Use double quotes as variables inside single quotes are not parsed:

```
echo $temperaturaMax = $row["MAX($namecolum)"];
```

OR

Second approach:

**Use alias:**

Corrected SQL:

```
$sql = "SELECT MAX($namecolum) as maxVal FROM $nametable";
echo $temperaturaMax = $row['maxVal'];
```

Comment: $nameVariable is undefined

Comment: Thanks! This works! Sorry in my code I had some errors with the name of variables. They are already corrected.

Answer (score 1):

`$row['MAX($nameVariable)']` won't work. Try this: `$row['MAX(' . $nameVariable . ')']`

Or, rename the column:

```
$sql = "SELECT MAX($namecolum) AS 'max' FROM '$nametable'";
echo $temperaturaMax = $row['max'] ;
```